# Can light fixture be installed in attic hatch?

Tags: electrical

This is a rather unusual scenario but is it compliant with the NEC to have a light fixture installed in a door that moves, e.g. an attic hatch? I have a hatch to my attic in the middle of a closet ceiling. Was curious if I can have Romex run to an electrical box on the attic side of that hatch, which would then move when the hatch is opened.

Answer (score 8):

Nothing in NEC section 410 prohibits the placement of a luminaire in or on a door or hatch.  However, you'll want to use a flexible cord pigtail with strain reliefs between a fixed junction box and the movable door as NM cable is not designed for repeated bending.  (Flexible cord is allowed here by 400.7(A)(9), BTW.)